# how to prevent memory leakage and high CPU usage?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on a  game using spritekit. I am in the final stages of developing the game but I have come across some difficulties with memory and CPU usage. I have noticed the CPU runs over 100% at times, mostly when I press the restart button. Also my memory increase at a rate of 0.3 MB every time I press the restart button. The first problem mostly occur only if I die right away in gameplay. I only have one scene.

The image provided below is from the allocation instrument.The spikes happen when I press the restart button or start of game. The 0.3 MB increment is in the debug navigator. Is there a difference between the two ?

Code for restart button:

The restart button is a SkspritNode

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  for touch in touches {
    let location = touch.location(in: self)

    if restartbuttons.contains(location) {
      let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 3)
      let nextScene = GameScene(size: (self.scene?.size)!)
      nextScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill

      self.scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)

      removeAllChildren()
      removeAllActions()
      removeFromParent()                  
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to run your code on `Runtime Sanitizer`. You will get the lines where your code is breaking.

Comment: this is difficult to diagnose without access to the project. there is nothing wrong with the code you posted here.